# double free or corruption error (Can't find error?)

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to create a class that will read from a file and calculate frequencies of trigrams, but for some reason I get this double free or corruption error and it crashes Visual Studio Code for me.

this is the .cpp

```
frequency::frequency(std::ifstream &infile)
{
  freqValue(infile);
}

std::vector<int> frequency::freqValue(std::ifstream &infile)
{
   std::vector<int> freqs(17576);
   char ch;
   while(infile.get(ch))
   {
       ch = tolower(ch);
       if(((ch -'a') >= 0 && (ch-'a') <= 26)) letters.push_back(ch);
   }

   int result = 0;
   for(size_t i = 0; i < letters.size() - 2; i++)
   {
       result += ((int) (letters[i] - 'a') *676);
       result += ((int)(letters[i + 1] - 'a') * 26);
       result += ((int)(letters[i+2] - 'a'));
       if (result == 17576) result -= 1;
       freqs[result] += 1;
       std::cout << freqs[result];
       result = 0;
   }
   return freqs;
}
```

this is the main

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc > 0)
    {
        std::ifstream infile;
        infile.open(argv[0]);
        frequency i(infile);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

and the header

```
class frequency
{
private:
   std::vector<char> letters;
   std::vector<int> frequencies;

public:
   frequency(std::ifstream &infile);
   std::vector<int> freqValue(std::ifstream &infile);
};

#endif
```

Comment: Why the double-spaced lines?

Comment: You should make sure that `result` is never grater than or equal to 17576

Comment: This is not enough `if (result == 17576) result -= 1;`

Comment: result cant ever be over 17576 because that is 26^3 and the math doesnt allow it to go over, also ust to test i said if( result >= 17576) result = 0; and my compiler still crashed.

Comment: Looks program does not agree with your math, how many letters is in that vector?

Comment: @EvanW. *result cant ever be over 17576 be* -- Instead of making assumptions, actually check your program.

Comment: Use `freqs.at(result)` and validate, your "math" looks suspicios.

Comment: Note if `letters.size()` is 0 or 1 you are getting out of bounds

Comment: *and my compiler still crashed.* -- There is nothing wrong with your compiler.  Your program has bugs and because of those bugs, your program crashes.  Time to learn how to use the debugger.

Comment: the math checks out, the max number for 'zzz' is 17575, but I found the error, in        if(((ch -'a') >= 0 && (ch-'a') <= 26)) letters.push_back(ch); it should be to 25 not 26 otherwise the ascii table values got all messed up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, the math for result checks out, I had checked that numerous times, but the issue is

```
if(((ch -'a') >= 0 && (ch-'a') <= 26)) letters.push_back(ch);
```

this it should be 25 not 26 otherwise it would take the ascii value one above Z aswell which would then allow it to go over 17576 making an error. Thank you though for all your input I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 issues in your program.

First:

```
 for(size_t i = 0; i < letters.size() - 2; i++)
```

condition for this loop should be improved:

```
 for(size_t i = 0; i + 2 < letters.size(); i++)
```

as `i` and `letters.size()` both unsigned, size of 1 or 0 will give underflow and out of bound access.

Second issue we do not know your data set, but I do not see why `result` cannot become greater than `17576` (for example 26 'z' in `letters` would make it) so you should at least check for that and report diagnostics. You may do that with assert if you do not want that check to happen in release mode.